Find out Active Directory username with correct case on Windows
What's the simplest way for a user to find out what their username is in Active Directory with the case (capital or lower-case letters) exactly as it's canonically stored in AD, in Windows 10/11?
For instance, for somebody with the username HarveyHope, getting exactly that string, and not harveyhope or the same letters in some other case?
The %USERNAME% environment variable and the whoami command return the username as the user typed it to log in to their workstation: so for a user logging in all lower-case it shows their username all lower-case; for a user who logs in mixed-case, it shows mixed-case, etc.
The best I've found is for a user to open a Command Prompt and type:
net /domain user %USERNAME% | findstr User.name

That returns their username the same way regardless of how they typed it to log in. Is there anything simpler (fewer punctuation marks or otherwise less likely to result in user error) that will yield this? Thank you.

Just curious, why do you need the exact case when Windows is not typically case-sensitive?

You could use powershell and query it directly on the domain controller, but as @squillman already pointed out, case is really not a problem for logon name, so you can just use %USERDOMAIN%\%USERNAME% or %USERNAME%@%USERDNSDOMAIN% already. And %USERNAME% probably already works for what you want to do too.

@squillman, For Putty to make an SSH connection to a Linux server which is authenticating users using Active Directory. It lets them straight in if the username is specified in the canonical case, but prompts for a password if their username has some other case variation. @LPChip, %USERNAME% was the first thing I thought of. It worked for me and many users, and it was baffling why it didn't work for some others.

Gotcha, that makes sense.


Instead of having the user type %USERNAME% (which is the wrong syntax for PowerShell anyway), have them type their actual username after the net user /dom. They're already accustomed to typing it.

Another command that might work without any parameters is klist to look at your Kerberos tickets. The "Client" Kerberos principal name is formed (in AD) from the sAMAccountName, and as far as I know, it's always canonicalized during the initial ticket retrieval – although I'm not 100% sure whether this works, but it's about 80% likely to work.



anything simpler (fewer punctuation marks or otherwise less likely to result in user error)

Yes – put the complex stuff in a script, put it on a file share, then have the user run it by path:
\\ad.example.com\netlogon\whoami

...or even deploy the script via GPO directly to each user's C:\Windows; then they'll be able to run it simply by name, e.g. C:\>  who or (if you make it a .vbs that shows a GUI popup) via Start menu. (For that matter, you can deploy scripts directly into the Start menu; it's just a folder.)
(You could probably even make a website that accepts Kerberos authentication and shows the user their user name; with Apache2 this would be mod_auth_gssapi – if the Kerberos 'klist' method works, then the webapp can be just one line that shows the received Kerberos principal; if not, then the webapp can find the user in LDAP instead.)
It doesn't matter how complex the real command is, if the user doesn't have to type it.
